# Ruby where clause is returning nil object? ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, arel

I'm getting the follow error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
```

Here is the where clause, the first one works.

```
def self.unpaid
  ARequest.where(:paid_on => nil).in(:status => [ARequest::TRANS_COMPLETE,ARequest::CANCELLED_BY]).gt(:total_owed_to_driver_in_cents => 0).asc(:assigned_driver_id).asc(:timestamp_requested)
end
```

This does NOT work.

```
def self.allcall
  longtimeago = Time.now - 60.day
  yesterday = Time.now - 1.day
  ARequest.where(["paid_on >= ? AND paid_on <= ?", longtimeago.beginning_of_day, yesterday.end_of_day]).in(:status => [ARequest::TRANS_COMPLETE,ARequest::CANCELLED_BY]).gt(:total_owed => 0).asc(:assigned_driver_id).asc(:timestamp_requested)
end
```

The above throws this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
```

CONTROLLER CODE

```
def allcalls
  ensure_root
  @calls = ARequest.allcall
end
```

ROUTE

```
get "sme/allcalls"
```

Comment: It would be easier to isolate the cause if you broke this method into multiple lines, e.g. `foo = Foo.where(…)\n foo = foo.in(…)\n foo = foo.gt(…)`.

Comment: Can you add the view please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to change

```
where(["paid_on >= ? AND paid_on <= ?", longtimeago.beginning_of_day, yesterday.end_of_day])
```

to

```
where("paid_on >= ? AND paid_on <= ?", longtimeago.beginning_of_day, yesterday.end_of_day)
```

Comment: Same error as before. What do I write to ask for all records? Just to be sure it isnt the query that is the issue.

Comment: Tried ARequest.find(:all) and still giving me the same error. Could this be something else?

Comment: Seems like your error comes from one of your view. Could you please put your code of the related view and controller action?

Comment: Can't be. The unpaid views, contorller, action all work. I copied all the unpaid stuff and made the all_calls query; I just changed the find method and it throws the error.

Comment: Your error message type is `ActionView` which indicates where the error comes from. Copied all the code doesn't means there won't be any problems. Probably there is just a variable name mismatch.